# Prove that if $\dim X'<\infty$ then $\dim X<\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have to prove that $\dim X'<\infty$ then $\dim X<\infty$ where $X$ is a normed vector space and $X'$ is a space of all linear and continuous functionals from $X$.

How can I prove this? I always try to figure out sth by myself before posting here, but this time I have no idea how can I prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\dim X'=n<\infty$. If $\dim X=\infty$ then $X$ contains an $n+1$ dimensional subspace $Y$. From linear algebra $\dim Y'=\dim Y=n+1$. On the other hand, $Y'\subset X'$, therefore $\dim Y'\leq \dim X'$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: If $\dim X < \infty$, then $\dim X' < \infty$

Hint 2: $X$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $X''$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. Again, we let $X'$ be the continuous dual.

Well, if $\dim X' < \infty$ then $\dim X'' = \dim X' < \infty$. But then note
$X \subset X''$ (using the canonical embedding) so $X$ is then finite dimensional!